# Creating mouse listener for every JLabel newly created

Tags: java, jlabel, mouselistener

I am building a family tree.  The application is creating one `JLabel` by pressing `JButton` (with the icon as the person's picture) with this code:

```
JButton newPersonButton = new JButton("New Person");
newPersonButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        final Data data = NewPerson.createPerson(frame);
            if (data != null) {

                if (Val == "mother") {

                    JLabel lblHomer = new JLabel(data.names);
                    lblHomer.setIcon(new ImageIcon(data.fileID));
                    cooX = cooX + 20;
                    cooY = cooY - 20;
                    panel_1.add(lblHomer, "cell " + cooX + " " + cooY);
                    panel_1.revalidate();
                }
```

I need a `JLabel` created dynamically by clicking an existing `JLabel`.  I can create another `JLabel` the same way I created the first one, and the new `JLabel` use the coordinates of the created `JLabel` as reference.  Not just one, I need **ALL** of the `JLabel`s to generated like that.  When I click on them then it creates another.  I know how to make one new `JLabel` by clicking on it:

```
JLabel lblHomer = new JLabel(data.names);
lblHomer.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

        final Data data = NewPerson.createPerson(frame);
        if (data != null) {

            String Val = data.CBvalue;

            if (Val == "mother") {

                JLabel lblHomer = new JLabel(data.names);    
                lblHomer.setIcon(new ImageIcon(data.fileID));    
                cooX = cooX + 20;
                cooY = cooY - 20;
                panel_1.add(lblHomer, "cell " + cooX + " " + cooY);
                panel_1.revalidate(); 
            }
        }
   }
```

But, I can't just copy/paste that same code infinitely.  I need to write a while loop or something to keep creating mouse listener for every `JLabel` I create.  I need help with that.

Whole code: http://pastebin.com/zLx1zK9Z

EDIT: Data.java:

```
public class Data {

    public final String names;
    public final String dateBirth;
    public final String bio;
    public final String fileID;
    public final String CBvalue;

    public Data(String names, String dateBirth, String bio, String fileID, String CBvalue) {
        this.CBvalue = CBvalue;
        this.names = names;
        this.dateBirth = dateBirth;
        this.bio = bio;
        this.fileID = fileID;
    }
// getters
}
```

Comment: Create a class that extends JLabel and has your `new MouseAdapter() {...` This way, when you create a new YourJLabel it will already have that MouseListener

Comment: @AlexandreSantos: no, there's no need to use inheritance here. The same MouseListener can be used on all JLabels, and it can easily be created with a simple factory method.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, extracting the MouseListener to a method. But creating his own class would teach him more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First...

```
 if (Val == "mother") {
```

Is not how you compare `String`s in Java, instead you should be using `"mother".equals(Val)`

Next, you could create a factory method which creates your labels, maybe even a utility class that has several different methods for creating yr labels, although I might consider a builder pattern of you got to this point...

```
public static JLabel createPersonLabel(Data data, MouseListener listener) {
    JLabel lblHomer = new JLabel(data.names);
    lblHomer.setIcon(new ImageIcon(data.fileID));
    lblHomer.addMouseListener(listener);
}
```

I would then create a custom `MouseListener` to handle the core functionary

```
public class DataMouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {

        final Data data = NewPerson.createPerson(frame);
        if (data != null) {

            String Val = data.CBvalue;

            if ("mother".equals(Val)) {

                JLabel lblHomer = createPersonalLabel(data, this);

                cooX = cooX + 20;
                cooY = cooY - 20;
                panel_1.add(lblHomer, "cell " + cooX + " " + cooY);
                panel_1.revalidate(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As an example. Your even create a custom `MouseListener` for each type data you might need

**Updated**

There are any number of options, for example, you could create a factory style method in your `NewFamilyTree` class that creates and adds the data label based on your needs and the data type...

```
protected void createAndAddDataLabel(Data data) {

    JLabel lblHomer = new JLabel(data.names);
    lblHomer.setIcon(new ImageIcon(data.fileID));

    cooX = cooX + 20;
    cooY = cooY - 20;

    panel_1.add(lblHomer, "cell " + cooX + " " + cooY);
    panel_1.revalidate();

    if (!"mother".equals(data.CBvalue)) {
        lblHomer.addMouseListener(new DataMouseHandler());
    }

}
```

Then call it from within your button...

```
JButton newPersonButton = new JButton("New Person");
newPersonButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        final Data data = NewPerson.createPerson(frame);
        if (data != null) {

            createAndAddDataLabel(data);

        }
    }
});
```

And, as an inner class, you could define the `DataMouseHandler`...

```
public class DataMouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        final Data data = NewPerson.createPerson(frame);
        if (data != null) {
            if ("mother".equals(Val)) {
                createAndAddDataLabel(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need this as an external class, you would need to pass the reference of the `NewFamilyTree`

```
public class DataMouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

    private NewFamilyTree tree;

    public DataMouseHandler(NewFamilyTree tree) {
        this.tree = tree;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        final Data data = NewPerson.createPerson(frame);
        if (data != null) {
            if ("mother".equals(Val)) {
                tree.createAndAddDataLabel(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated**

Now, having said all that, this is a classic example of where a [Model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) approach would be most suitable.

What you should be doing is modelling the family tree in some way, which is divorced from the UI, so it simply focuses on the requirements of the model, how it's structured and how it's managed.

The model would provide feedback from event notification when it's changed in some way.

From there you would wrap a UI around it, so the UI would simply be responsible for rendering the output of the model.

The controller would take actions from the UI and update the model accordingly, which will in turn trigger updates from the model to the UI...

Comment: So where do the values of cooX, cooY, and panel_1 come from when mouseClicked is invoked?

Comment: Either they need to be past, maybe as part if a model, or they are instance variables accessible  as an inner class. But there's no details in the original question to make a judgement question. How were you intending to solve it?

Comment: In the original question, the variables would have had to be part of an enclosing scope for the fragment to compile.  The OP mentioned having to replicate this code multiple times; one of the reasons I think he's doing that is to have the individual label information available.  You are proposing a factory method to get a label with a generic mouse handler attached, which is fine.  But the mouse handler has to have the info about the label clicked on, and I think the example should show some way that can happen so the OP and other readers sees what's involved in a generic solution.

Comment: Yes, I need info about every `JLabel`. I tried yesterday for couple of hours with both your ideas but couldn't make anything working...

I don't understand that, yes, how to get values of cooX, cooY, panel_1, even frame in this example... I know I should've figured that by myself somehow, but I'm not (yet) so good at this. :D

Btw. thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Arcy the problem is, there's not enough information to make a determination about the state of the other variables, so it's not possible to make a suggestion about them. The recommendation is make use of the idea and adjust it to meet the current requirements. Given the fact that two of the values are primitives, they will either need to instance variables on enclosing class approach or passed as part of so e type of model. The parent panel could also be passed as a reference to the handler. It is an abstract concept to an abstract problem, until the OP can provide more context...

Comment: @Tinmar Because you didn't provide a complete example, I have no idea under what context all those variables are been used. The ideas presented are abstract with the intention that you would fill in the available blanks. Unless you can provide more context to your answer, I fail to see how anybody is going to be able to provide you fully workable example in one step

Comment: Yes, my bad, I would like to provide needed context, but I don't know what exactly should I show to you... so - here is my whole working code. http://pastebin.com/nLRLdpZR
@MadProgrammer, you helped me with code about week ago, remember? That's the almost same code, you suggested me even using `JTree`, and this is my idea of avoiding `JTree`...

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, there are a couple of ways to do this.  I think the first suggestion is probably best, based on what little I/we understand of what you want to do.

```
public class ListenerLabel extends JLabel implements MouseListener
{
  public void mouseExited() {}
  public void mouseEntered() {}
  // etc.
  public void mouseClicked() {}
  {
    // here put the code you have for creating another person
    // 'this' refers to the label that was clicked on; you can get coordinates
    // and whatever you need from that.
  }
}
```

Now instead of creating JLabels to hold your people, you create ListenerLabels; they will interact with your UI just the same as JLabels, but have this extra feature of listening for their own clicks.  And their name might be something do with people instead of listening, if they're going to contain code specific to people.  ('PeopleLabels', or whatever).

-- edit -- more detail, as requested.

As I look at this again, it seems to me your `NewPerson.createPerson()` method must be popping up a dialog or something to get information for the new person.  I will continue the example assuming that works, though I'd probably have done that differently.

```
public void mouseClicked()
{
  final Data data = NewPerson.createPerson(frame);
  if (data != null)
  {
    if (data.CBvalue.equals("mother"))  // I would use a constant or enums here instead
    {
      ListenerLabel label = new ListenerLabel(data.names);
      label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(data.fileID));
      int xPosition = this.getX() + 20;
      int yPosition = this.getY() - 20;
      JPanel enclosingPanel = (JPanel)this.getParent();
      enclosingPanel.add(label, "cell " + cooX + " " + cooY);
      // set position of new label here?
      enclosingPanel.revalidate();
    }
  }
}
```

Adding the new panel to the enclosing panel (which is panel_1 in your example, I assume) is a little 'black magic' to me -- unless that panel has a special layout manager, or you've extended JPanel so that `add()` means something special, I don't see how that's going to do anything useful.  But this more-filled-out method shows where to get the existing label coordinates, a way to get the panel enclosing the two labels, and a suggestion where I would expect you to *set* the position of the new label.

There are a lot of assumptions here, because you haven't shown us executable code.  I know it's difficult to extract running code out of a larger system, but be aware (you and other readers) that any answer for incomplete code is based on partly on assumptions made filling it in and partly on assumptions not made about what else is needed or coded elsewhere.

Comment: I am trying to make that @MadProgrammer idea to work, but I want learn to so it this way, too. Ok, I created new class as you suggested, but I'm not sure what to put in mouseClicked() method. Putting `.this` seems logical here, so am I creating some kind of constructor here, with getters/setters for my values?

And thank you for the answer. ;)

Comment: I looked there; there's over 300 lines of code, and I don't see the Data class.  It's why you often see requests on SO for posters to boil their problem down to a very small code set, and to post it rather than linking to it.  So often one follows a link only to find there are things missing.  Does the code I filled in for `mouseClicked()` help?

Comment: I have one error, it says: `The constructor NewFamilyTree.JLabelListen(String) is undefined`. Sorry for missing data class, I'll edit first post and put it there, it's very short...

Comment: `JLabelListen` is `LisenerLabel` in my code, same thing, different name.

Comment: @Tinmar I can't tell if you still need help getting this to work, or what your problem is if you can't.  You said you weren't sure what to put in mouseClicked(), so I added more detail to that.  Are you still having problems?